# Angular/Mongoose Saving a form with a list of documents

Tags: angularjs, mongoose

I'm trying to save a new Post (this is just a simple example) that has a list of documents using a form. Is there a way accomplish this?

Model

```
var Post = new Schema({
  message: String,
  tags: [
      { name: String }
  ]
})
```

HTML

```
<form novalidate ng-submit="SavePost(post)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="post.message">
    <input type="text" ng-model="post.tags.name">
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```

The controller and API are working, so the message is being saved. The issue is: **how to structure the form so multiple tags are saved as well**.

Here is just a simple example where tags are a list of documents that have only one key ("name"). I had a  working on a similar problem. What if I had documents with two or more keys?

Answer (score 0):

Export your model.

```
module.exports = Post;
```

In postCtrl.js import your model and export method below (I'm using express)

```
var Post = require('../models/Post.js');

exports.save = function(req, res){
    var post = req.body.post;
    Post.create(post, function(err, post) {
        if(err) {
            res.status(400);
            return res.send({reason: err.toString()});
        }
        res.send(post);
    });
});
```

After that just import postCtrl to your routing and define route:

```
app.post('/api/post', postCtrl.save);
```